# How to show common contacts in a phonegap app

Tags: android, ios, cordova

My aim is to build an app that can detect other users in your contact list that have the app installed. I think the closest model would be the way whatsapp handles contacts.

The only way I could think of doing this is by obtaining the users telephone number (which for security reasons is not an option) and comparing with other registered app users.

So, I'm not sure how I could best approach this without the use of the phone number.

I'm looking for an abstract solution rather than a concrete example.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided that the best way to achieve this is to have a user verify their phone number.

Enter phone number.
Send text to user with verification code.
Let them enter verification code and validate it with the phone number they supplied.

That way I can be sure of two things:

1. The number is entered correctly.
2. The user owns that number.